# show() a div that's hidden with children() (drag and drop)

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, show-hide

First question here :)

Im working with some drag and drop divs and I want to show hidden content when dropped into a specific div.

Here is my drop function:

```
function drop(ev) {

    ev.preventDefault();

    var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

    if($(ev.target).hasClass("items")){

        $(ev.target).children('div').children('.post').hide();
    }
    else if($(ev.target).hasClass("dropzone")) {

        $(ev.target).children('div').children('.post').show();
    }
}
```

Comment: $(ev.target).children('div').children('.post').hide(); works but the show doesn't

Comment: What's your question, exactly?  What's not working?

Comment: Could you possibly post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) live demo, at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or similar, to show your problem? With the relevant HTML?

Comment: Everything is working like intendet until "$(ev.target).children('div').children('.post').show();"

Comment: What are you trying to drop and in what?Sorry your question in not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DragDrop/Drag_Operations